# Close open files when remote desktop session disconnected

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-server

We have a server application sitting on 'server A' that has its own database split up in to multiple database files. We have multiple users that dial in via remote desktop to 'server B' and then launch the client version of this application that accesses the database files stored on 'server A'.

Our problem is that users don't always log off properly from 'server B' - they just click the 'X' to disconnect.

This is causing the database files to be left open on 'server A' which causes us issues with licensing (only so many number of database files can be open at once). So if we were to look on 'server A' under Computer Management > Shared Folders > Open Files, we would see the database files still open even though the user is not logged in remotely to 'server B'.

Is there a way to automatically close the open files associated to the user if they disconnect or log off from their session?

We have set the remote server (server B) to end a disconnected session after 1 minute - is that enough?